# How can I open and show a weblink in a tablet connected to my computer. maybe an Electron app, Cordova, Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, electron

I have a tablet android connected in my computer using usb.

I need to open in the tablet some URL (like  mydomain.com?uuid=1234) clicking from my desktop (from a intranet or enterprise system). In fact my url is my service to allow the user sign a document. So instead to open in the desktop, I need to display this link in a tablet to allow someone in front of the desk sign documents in my weblink in the tablet.

This procedure must be transparent to the user.
Just need to clik some button in the intranet or enterprise system in desktop and open in the tablet my weblink.

I don't know the best approach to complete this task. I read that is not possible to use electron in mobile but perhaps in mirror mode?! I read about electron, Cordova ,Ionic, deeplinks...The tablet will be used only for this purpose connected to the front desk computer to sign with my application, nothing else.

Comment: Heres a good guide to get you started: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links